# How to filter a list of objects based on a dynamically created collection of predicates

Tags: kotlin, filter

I am working on a searching/filtering functionality where a user should be able to filter a list of events to fit a pattern which he will make in runtime.

I made a function filter which is looping over all the constraints the user has set, and then filtering the result.

My problem is that I am copying the list many times, and I was wondering if there is a way where I can do this kind of complex filtering in a more declarative (kotlin-) way without side effects.

```kotlin
fun filter(query: Filter, eventsIn: List<Event>): List<Event> {
        var events = eventsIn
        query.filters.forEach { filter ->
            if (filter.key is EventFiltersListStuff){
                events = when (filter.key as EventFiltersListStuff) {
                    PLACE -> events.filter { event -> (filter.value as List<*>).contains(event.location.place) }
                    AREA -> events.filter { event -> (filter.value as List<*>).contains(event.location.area) }
                    CATEGORY -> events.filter { event -> (filter.value as List<*>).any{it in event.category} }
                    GENRE -> events.filter { event -> (filter.value as List<*>).contains(event.genre) }
                }
            } else {
                events = when (filter.key as EventFilters) {
                    TITLE -> events.filter { event -> event.title.contains(filter.value as String, true) }
                    PRICELT -> events.filter { event -> event.price <= filter.value as Int }
                    PRICEGT -> events.filter { event -> event.price >= filter.value as Int }
                    TIMELT -> events.filter { event -> event.time <= filter.value as Int }
                    TIMEGT -> events.filter { event -> event.time >= filter.value as Int }
                }
            }
        }
        return events
    }
```

The model looks like this

```kotlin
data class Event(
        val title: String,
        val genre: String,
        val image: String,
        val link: String,
        val category: List<String>,
        val price: Int,
        val text: String,
        val tickets: String,
        var time: Long,
        val location: Location
)
```

I have two enums one is for inclusive filtering, where a user can filter a list based on multiple instances of the attribute in focus.

The other one is non inclusive, and will just remove all entities which is not matching the query.

```kotlin
enum class EventFiltersListStuff(val str: String, ) : FilterType {
    PLACE("place"),
    AREA("area"),
    CATEGORY("category"),
    GENRE("genre");

    override fun str(): String = str
}
enum class EventFilters(val str: String, ) : FilterType {
    PRICELT("priceLT"),
    PRICEGT("priceGT"),
    TIMELT("timestampLT"),
    TIMEGT("timestampGT"),
    TITLE("title");

    override fun str(): String = str
}
```

*The next code block is less relevant, but I'll include is for transparency, Because it is used in the function which is the core of my question.*

```kotlin
interface FilterType {
    fun str(): String
}

class Filter private constructor(val filters: Map<FilterType, Any>) {
    class Builder {
        private var filters: MutableMap<FilterType, Any> = mutableMapOf()
        fun filters(key: FilterType, value: Any) = apply {
            this.filters[key] = when (this.filters[key]) {
                is List<*> -> (this.filters[key] as List<*>) + listOf(value)
                is Comparable<*> -> listOf(this.filters[key], value)
                else -> value
            }
        }

        fun build(): Filter {
            return Filter(filters)
        }
    }
}
```

*I am also using the `Filter` to generate a filter in a GraphQL query, this is the reason I am having strings in the enums.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and efficient solution would be just to filter each event with conjunction of all filters.

```kotlin
typealias SingleFilter = Map.Entry<FilterType, Any> // you may want to remodel it as a sealed class, more on that later

fun SingleFilter.isMatching(event: Event): Boolean = ...

fun List<Event>.applyFilters(filters: List<SingleFilter>) = filter { event -> filters.all { it.isMatching(event) }
```

---

Your model could be greatly improved by remodeling your filters as a sealed class, replacing instance checks and enums with polymorphism. This will have a huge benefit of being type-safe. You can create a hierarchy with two groups for your two filtering cases. You can define mapping between filter names and classes in different part of your code, decoupling serialization from filter logic.

Comment: Thank you this looks awesome, I will try it out soon

Comment: I did it with sealed classes and polymorphism. Thanks